# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to dockers, but I am also surprised with below error in my build stage,

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Xi2.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Notice that the error doesn't exist before and the stage build works normally.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

this is an issue with Gitlab.com. You can check the status here: https://status.gitlab.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response, i added a caption in my original post. Please how can i solve the issue?

Comment: You can either wait for Gitlab to solve the issue or move to a different registry

Comment: you think that it should take much time .?? tomorrow will it be resolved?